# Coaching centre or self study?

Tags: career-path

I'm currently 15 and I still have around 2 more years here at my school in India. I took admission in a reputed coaching centre here for my career oriented studies last year. I want to be a student at the Indian Institute of Technology (which is the best in India in terms of engineering and technology, and whose exam - the Joint Entrance Examination (JEE) I am bound to give in 2019) and my coaching centre prepares me for the same, and shall continue to do so for the next couple of years. The quality and level of teaching at my centre is, without doubt, great.

However, I have friends at my school who, without going to any such coaching centre, can match or perhaps outsmart me in several fields of study, by simply just studying and researching at their homes through the internet, books and other sources. This fact leaves me in a state of dilemma regarding my decision of joining the coaching centre. I don't regret my decision, but I'm just starting to feel a little sceptical about it, because when I started to self study like some of my friends, I felt that I could do perhaps as much the same level of study, or even better (than my coaching centre), by just studying on my own.

The biggest advantage of such methodology is, in my opinion, that you can study at your own pace, unlike at a coaching centre where study is time bound. Those guys can delve deeper into any topic of their choice, without any sort of pressure.

From the past couple of months, I am studying differential calculus on my own, which shall be taught to me at my institute after a month or so. I think I'm doing pretty well and am going good at it, without any guidance or assistance. I have been able to solve many of the questions that my institute has to offer regarding the topic. So the thing which is troubling me is that can't I do this for other subjects and topics as well? And in this way, I won't be requiring any formal help and support for my studies. This is what some of my pals have resorted to.

But one advantage which I feel students like me have over such students as my friends, is that we get an exposure to the exam pattern and are quite accustomed to the time bound type of exams. Furthermore, we can get to know our ranks at various levels and thus improve accordingly. For example, at my coaching centre, I give several periodic tests which give me an insight into my performance, and where I need to improve. I also get to know my rank at the national level, which is quite a boost for me.

I won't be leaving my coaching centre for the next 2 years to study at my own, but I just want to know if students like my friends, who do not go (and do not wish to go) to any such coaching centre, do they have any significant advantages over students like me, who go to an institute for academic assistance?

Comment: Sorry, this site doesn't handle questions about undergraduate admissions.  See http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This is not a question regarding admissions. See the tag used, it's 'career-path'

Comment: You might be able to resuscitate your question by asking people to weigh the advantages and disadvantages of self study vs. institutional study.  But even then it could get closed by virtue of varying from one person to another.

Comment: Graduate students do not have the "coaching centre" problem that you are facing. Voting to close.

Comment: The people I am talking about, including me, are neither graduate nor undergraduate. We are just school students, as I have mentioned.

Comment: Let me, painfully and clearly, spell it out for you: this is not the appropriate site for high school questions.

Comment: @MadJack The reason I voted to close was because the OP claims that it's about career path. If the OP specifies that it's about admission, I would vote to "Leave it to Open". Please see my [meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/775/546) three years ago.